# Golang interface of different types - confusion when passing by value

Tags: go

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aW_xVM_e5sf)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

// types
type square struct {
    length float64
}
type circle struct {
    radius float64
}

type shape interface {
    area() float64
}

// methods
func (c circle) area() float64 {
    return math.Pi * c.radius * c.radius
}
func (s square) area() float64 {
    return s.length * s.length
}

func main() {
    c := circle{
        radius: 2.5,
    }
    s := square{
        length: 25.5,
    }
    info(c)
    info(s)
}

func info(s shape) {
    x := s.area()
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

this all works as expected, however, I don't fully understand why. I understand what is going on in terms of creating the interface with the structs, however, what confuses me is how we under `func main()` after creating type literals of `circle` and `square` when I pass the arguments `info(c)` and `info(s)` how Go understands which method we are calling with the right argument. I feel like there may need to be type assertion involved of some sort with:

```golang
func info(s shape) {
    if s.(type) == circle {
        c.area()
    }
}
```

Go knows that type shape is going to be either circle or square and then in the background is Go doing that type selection for us? I hope my question was clear enough, thank you.

Comment: Under the hood there is a kind of vtable which is used to look up the right method from an interface value. But this is not some kind of type switch. The language is doing just the appropriate thing here.

Comment: alright, thanks, I guess I'll just need more practice with it before it finally "clicks" as to what's going on.

Comment: The trick, if we can call it a "trick", is that any interface *value* holds two things: the *concrete type*, and the value-of-that-type. Think of it as a sort of secret struct: `type hidden struct secret { type *T; value *V }`. Then `var i some_interface_type; ...; i = expr` really does `tmp = expr; i = hidden{type: &the_type; value: &tmp}`.

Comment: Your `if s.(type)` test is accessing the `type` part of this hidden secret structure. Writing `s.(circle)` literally asserts that the type is `circle`, and then accesses the value part.

Comment: Note that there are no promises about the layout of the secret structure, or the things inside it. I made them two pointers here, and in fact they are currently pointers, but there's some desire to have "small" values inlined.

Comment: thanks @torek it helped clarify more

Answer (score 0):

> Go knows that type shape is going to be either circle or square

No. Go knows that both types [*implement*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) [the `shape` interface](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9). This makes it possible to use instances of `circle` and `square` as arguments for `func info(s shape)`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, if it doesn't know which type then how does it know the correct method to call? I guess that's where I am caught up at.

Comment: @Ctfrancia *"if it doesn't know which type"* you're thinking about this incorrectly. There's no scenario in which an interface value doesn't know its dynamic type. An interface value is always made up of two pointers, one pointing to the dynamic type's information, one pointing to the dynamic data.